# Creating a Random list with constraints

Tags: list-manipulation

I need something similar to the List below, but not totally random and values within each individual column and row remaining the same:

```
xyCoord = RandomReal[{-2, 25}, {270, 219, 2}];
```

The above is not what is required.  I need

> `{{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}.........{x1,y219}}, {{x2, y1,}, {x2, y2}.........., {x2, y219}},..............,{{x270, y1},.........................,{x270, y219}}`

I need `x1 > x2> x3...... > x270`.
Same for y need `y1 > y2 >   y219`.

Each xi and yi (i being index number) is selected randomly within these constraints.

The final list should have the following dimensions.....

```
Dimensions[xyCoord] = {270, 219, 2}
```

Comment: Do you want a sorted list as already provided, or do you want the random number generated at each step to be generated in the range `{lastX, 25}`? i.e. do you want `xcoord =Flatten@NestList[
  RandomReal[{Last@#, 25}, 1] &, {-2}, 270]` similarly for y, then proceed as JasonB suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Your command will generate `270*219*2 = 118260` random numbers, but from your description, you only want `270+219` random numbers.  This should work,

```
xcoord = RandomReal[{-2, 25}, 270];
ycoord = RandomReal[{-2, 25}, 219];
xycoord = Outer[List, Reverse@Sort@xcoord, Reverse@Sort@ycoord];
```

Here is an example output if I change the 270 and 219 to 10 and 10

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Tuples[]` seems like a better choice here.

Comment: You mean like `Tuples[{Sort@xcoord, Sort@ycoord}]`?  But then you would need to use `Partition` to shape it into a three-dimensional array right?

Comment: Huh, I didn't notice that the OP wanted a nested list. Sorry 'bout that...

Answer (score 3):

```
xcoord = Reverse@Sort@RandomReal[{-2, 25}, 270];
ycoord = Reverse@Sort@RandomReal[{-2, 25}, 219];
Table[{x, y} , {x, xcoord}, {y, ycoord}]
```

Another way is this (as mentioned in comments):

```
Partition[ Tuples[{xcoord, ycoord}] , Length@ycoord]
```

which is useful to know especially if you want to flatten the list anyway you can just use `Tuples[{xcoord, ycoord}]`

Comment: Well done. Good Answer. Although, you forgot the sort@ on the ycoord.

Comment: oops, fixed....